# How to push objects from an array to firstore in angular

Tags: angular, angularfire

I have a json file which I want to push all the objects in the json file to firestore

This is how the json look like

```
[
   {
      "John":23m,
      "Mike":34m,
      "Adam":12m
   },
   {
      "John":45m,
      "Mike":45m,
      "Adam":67m
   },
   {
      "John":90m,
      "Mike":4m,
      "Adam":2m
   },
   {
      "John":23m,
      "Mike":3m,
      "Adam":1m
   },
   {
      "John":230m,
      "Mike":334m,
      "Adam":132m
   }
]
```

In my ts file, I used `http.get()` to retrieve the data

```
public url='assets/data.json';
public rowData=[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.retrieve()
    .subscribe(data => this.rowData =data);
}


retrieve():Observable<DataInterface[]>{
    return  this.http.get<DataInterface[]>(this.url)
};
```

Now i want to push `rowData` to firestore

I tried this:

```
uploadToFirestore(){
    return this.firestore.collections('data').add(this.rowData)
    //I got an error showing that I can't send Array to firestore 
}
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: I don't know the firestore, but don't send an array, if it's not supported! Try to create an object out of it, like: this.firestore.collections('data').add({ mydata: this.rowData }); Does that work?

Comment: I am trying it to see the outcome

Comment: @JanosVinceller perfect but only the first object was sent and it multiplied itself so many times

Comment: @JanosVinceller Please add that as an answer so Awabil can accept your answer and close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create an object out of it, like:

```
this.firestore.collections('data').add({ mydata: this.rowData });
```